# What is the difference between ReentrantLock vs stampedlock? Which one to prefer?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, locking, reentrantlock

What should be the use cases for choosing between ReentrantLock and StampedLock?
For example, Which lock should be chosen if I have 10 Readers and 10 Writers?
And which one to choose if i have 20 Readers and 1 writers?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094200/what-is-stamped-locks-in-java

Comment: @Thilo This question does not answer my question related to readers and writers. Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @Thilo Are you deliberately downvoting my other questions also?

Comment: @Veeram I could not find any solution for my problems on Stackoverflow, so i posted the questions. And in the meanwhile when i tried i found the solution myself. That is why i posted the answers too. Is there any fault in doing this? Even for this particular question, I have not got any perfect solution. I don't think downvoting the questions from your side is valid.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a point here. All I'm saying is try first for a little while before you post your questions. Please read the api docs.

Comment: @Veeram You are just over using your rights of down voting.

Comment: like I said I'm not trying to make a point here. I'll go ahead n remove the downvote if thats all you care if I can.

Comment: @Veeram Voting matters. Pls remove your down votes.

Comment: The documentation is quite detailed, so you really should at least point out which part of the documentation is unclear

Comment: @KaranVerma I have not voted (either way) on any of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReentrantLock` is, as its name and [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) say, reentrant. StampedLock is not.

StampedLock is a low-level building block with some fragile behavior and complex interaction with the java memory model. Its use should be avoided unless you understand all its properties and have profiled code to determine that something is actually bottlenecked on locking.